# Strange performance difference of matrix row summation with RowMajor and ColMajor data arrangement

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, memory, eigen

I decided to check how data arrangement in matrix influences performance of simple operations.
I wrote simple row summation algorithm using `Eigen::Matrix` as data storage.
I though that RowMajor storage should demostrate better performance due to better cache utilization.

I used `g++` compiler with `-O2` option and it gives me following results:

ColMajor: `40791546 µs`
RowMajor: `28790948 µs`

It's pretty ok. But with `-O3` it gives me really strange difference:

ColMajor: `10353619 µs`
RowMajor: `28359348 µs`

And it looks like ColMajor becomes really fast with `-O3`. Why switching from `-O2` to `-O3` changes performance so drastically?

My CPU: intel i7-6700K, gcc version: `7.5.0-3ubuntu1~19.10`

My "benchmark":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include "Eigen/Core"


template<typename DerivedMat, typename DerivedRes>
void runTest(const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedMat> &mat, Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedRes> &res) {
    const int64_t nRows = mat.rows();
    const int64_t nCols = mat.cols();
    for(int64_t row = 0; row < nRows; ++row){
        for(int64_t col = 0; col < nCols; ++col){
            res(row, 0) += mat(row, col);
        }
    }
}


const int64_t nRows = 300;
const int64_t nCols = 5000;
const int nAttempts = 20000;

template<int Alignment>
void bench() {
    Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, Alignment> mat(nRows, nCols);
    srand(42);
    mat.setRandom();

    Eigen::VectorXf res(nRows);
    res.setZero();

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int iter = 0; iter < nAttempts; ++iter)
        runTest(mat, res);
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Elapsed " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[µs]" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    bench<Eigen::ColMajor>();
    //bench<Eigen::RowMajor>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ColMajor`-based loop is much faster in `-O3` because GCC 7.5 is able to automatically vectorize it as opposed to the `RowMajor`-based loop. You can see that [in the assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/ERq29m) (`L11`-labelled loop).
Automatic vectorization is [not performed by GCC in `-O2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html).

Indeed, mentioned cache effects are relevant especially for *big matrices that do not fit in cache* and vectorization can be more important than cache-efficiency for relatively small matrices. The problem is that GCC have some difficulties with the vectorization of simple reductions.
You can help him using OpenMP directives such as `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:accumulatorVar)` for example. Alternatively, you can use row-wise summations provided by Eigen that should be vectorized (especially for contiguous data).
The resulting code should be the fastest of all previous codes.
[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/eCtUDf) is the resulting assembly code.